# WebGL in Firefox - Debian Squeeze

Tags: graphics, firefox, opengl

I'm trying to get working WebGL on Firefox without success, I tried forcing WebGL in the Firefox configuration and updating the Mesa drivers, but it's still not working. It's working on Opera, so the problem isn't the driver...
I have an integrated Intel HD Graphics...

about:support:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Adapter Description Tungsten Graphics, Inc -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
Device ID   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
Driver Version  2.1 Mesa 7.10.3
GPU Accelerated Windows 0/1 Basic
Vendor ID   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
windowLayerManagerRemote    false
AzureCanvasBackend  cairo
AzureContentBackend none
AzureFallbackCanvasBackend  none
```

Graphic card info:

```
# lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

OpenGL version

```
# glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile  x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

about:config (webgl properties):

```
webgl.can-lose-context-in-foreground;true
webgl.default-no-alpha;false
webgl.disable-extensions;false
webgl.disabled;false
webgl.enable-draft-extensions;false
webgl.force-enabled;true
webgl.force-layers-readback;false
webgl.lose-context-on-heap-minimize;false
webgl.max-warnings-per-context;32
webgl.min_capability_mode;false
webgl.msaa-force;false
webgl.prefer-16bpp;false
webgl.prefer-native-gl;false
webgl.shader_validator;true
```

I tried the WebGL test get.webgl.com, but it says that the browser support it but is not activated...

Any suggestion??

Comment: What are the values of `webgl.disabled` and other `webgl.` preferences (in `about:config`)?

Comment: I posted the values of webgl config!

Comment: Just to make sure, the message you are getting is: *"Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card."*?

Comment: Yes, that's the message